# "Reset this PC"

Tags: dual-boot

I have dual boot with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to reset my Windows, as well as delete the Linux partitions and allocate my whole SSD back to a fresh Windows 10 installation.

Would selecting "Reset this PC" delete the partitions, and install Windows as the only OS on my SSD? And is this safe to do?

Comment: This isn't an ubuntu question.

Answer (score -2):

You can make it ignore Ubuntu and boot straight into Windows each time by doing the following in the terminal (Ubuntu).

- Boot up your machine and remember what slot Ubuntu is in and Windows is in in grub
- Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Use the arrow keys to navigate to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` and change it to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.
- Then change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` and replace `0` with whatever slot Windows was in in grub, for example `GRUB_DEFAULT=3`.
- Go into terminal and type in `sudo update-grub`
- Windows should now boot normally.

To manually remove the partitions, type in **Disk Management** in your Start Menu and open it up. Simply right click all the partitions that relate to Linux and choose **Delete Volume**, or whatever option is very similar to that.

Once your PC boots directly into Windows, and you've deleted your Linux partitions, you should be good!